# Migrating from react-native-navigation to react-navigation

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I'm migrating a bit of an older project from `react-native-navigation` to `react-navigation`, however I can't seem to figure out how to 'unregister' the original `react-native-navigation` view.

So what I did was 'reverse' the installation docs of `react-native-navigation` converting `NavigationActivity` back to `ReactActivity`:

```java
// MainActivity.java
// convert back to `extends ReactActivity`
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // onCreate change required by react-navigation
        super.onCreate(null);
    }
}
```

And also in MainApplication:

```java
// MainApplication.java
// get rid of `NavigationApplication`
public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {
    private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
            new ReactNativeHost(this) {
                @Override
                protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
                    return "index";
                }
                @Override
                public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
                    return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
                }
                @Override
                public List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
                    ArrayList<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
                    packages.addAll(Arrays.asList());
                    packages.add(new RNAppVersionPackage());
                    return packages;
                }
            };
    @Override
    public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
        return mReactNativeHost;
    }
}
```

Per the docs these are the only changes required to setup `react-native-navigation`, so I would expect I can now just register a normal component in `index.js` of my app like so:

```js
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './src/App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

However this does not work. When the app starts it is stuck on an empty screen. What I'm thinking is that `react-native-navigation` is still somewhere else registering a no longer existing root component, which is no longer defined. Note that I'm not yet using any functionality from `react-navigation`. The `App` component is just a view with some text.

Does anyone know if/where I need to make some changes to completely get rid of `react-native-navigation` handling the rootview of the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did to fix this was generate a new 'clean' react-native project on the same version and copy the new `MainActivity.java` and `MainApplication.java` over. Don't forget to change the `package` and imports if you have any. Also make sure the `MainComponentName` (if using any) matches the expected component name in `AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);`

Finally clear all cache and the project should now run fine.